# How can i store Json data in Redis?

Tags: redis, node-redis, redisjson

I want to use Hash of Redis and store a JSON Object in one key and Array in other. 
How i can achieve this.

For example when i run this:

```
redis.hmset(`channel`, 'key1', 'someValue', 'key2', [{x: 1}])
```

then it gives the error.

But if i change the value of key2 to string it store it in form of string.
I wnat to store the JSON data. How can i do so?

I am using Node and [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) npm package.

Comment: which language? which client?

Comment: updated question, using node

Comment: Do you just need to get/set JSON as a blob or also in place update and perhaps partial retrieve?

Comment: @GuyKorland he said about his case on the comments section of my answer - i mentioned your name too.

Comment: @GuyKorland i need to set JSON data and get from the hash and also update the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to store an array in Redis Hash.

But, you can use the Redis Module [RedisJSON](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/) which adds native JSON support to Redis. It has couple of node.js clients you can use.

e.g. [redis-modules-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-modules-sdk) and [redis-rejson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-rejson)